# Creating Dynamic attributes from MongoDB collection - YII Framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to create dynamic attributes from MongoDB Collection object name in YII framework.
I am using YIIMongoDBSuite extension can anybody provide idea for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Using `save()` function of `EmongoDocument` use insert and pass parameter so that it will save the attributes what ever you pass.